# How to use get_posts() and form select

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hi everyone I'm new to wp plugin development. So far, I'm doing well except for this form select piece that seems to be kicking my head. I'm trying to show list of recent post in a select field for admin to select and do some stuff but the title will not show. I tried this in radio button and even text field and got no result. Please, what am I missing in this form?

```
<form method="post"><select name="Article">
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );     foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

echo'<option value='".the_ID()."'>'".the_title()."'</option>';
endforeach;
echo"</select></form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test right now, but there are a couple of possibilities.

First, `the_ID()` will echo the value immediately - it won't work as you'd like in the middle of a concatenation.  You need `get_the_ID()` instead.

Second, the matching of your quotes seems odd when you're `echo`ing the `option`.  Assuming you want the output to be something like

```
<option value="1">Title</option>
```

your `echo` should be

```
echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

it won't work as you'd like in the middle of a concatenation. You need `get_the_ID($post)` instead.

```
  <?php 
        $args = array( 'numberposts=>-1&order=>ASC&orderby=>title' );
        $postslist = get_posts( $args );     foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<option value="'.get_the_id($post).'">'.get_the_title($post).'</option>';
        endforeach;
?>
```

your `echo` should be

```
echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID($post) . '">' . get_the_title($post) . '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<select name="posts">';
    $args = 'numberposts=-1&order=ASC&orderby=title&post_type=post';
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($postslist as $post){
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<option value="'.get_the_id($post).'">'.get_the_title($post).'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Enjoy